# Quicksort Interview Question: Quicksort run three times

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic, quicksort

A question I got on recent interview:

> Consider an array with n elements which is divided into three parts:
>
> ```
> A[1] .....................................................A[n]
> part1(m1)..........part2(m2)......... part3(m3)
> ```
>
> Then quick sort is run on it three times as follows:
>
> ```
> QuickSort(A[m1+1.....n])
> QuickSort(A[1.....m1+m2])
> QuickSort(A[m1+1.....n])
> ```
>
> Under what condition is the array is sorted?
>
> ```
> a) m1>m2
> b) m1<m2
> c) m1>=m2
> d) m1=m2=m3
> ```

My answer was `m1>m2` but now I am in doubt whether `m1>=m2` is also correct. Is this right?

Comment: are m1 m2 and m3 the sizes of the parts?

Comment: @rpattiso good question. I assumed they are the indexes where the array is split. @ user3802426 you should clarify

Comment: yes m1 m2 m3 are the sizes of the parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I claim that `m1 <= m2` is necessary and sufficient.

1. If it is the case, after the first we can be sure that `m2` smallest numbers from the `m1 + 1 ... n` part are located inside the `1 ... m1 + m2` prefix. `m2` >= `m1`, thus `m1` smallest numbers are inside the `1 ... m1 + m2` prefix. It means that after the second run they will be on their correct positions. It does not matter what's going on in the `m1 + 1 ... n` part because it will be fixed during the last run anyway.
2. If it is not the case, it is easy to build a counter example: {3, 3, 1, 2, 2}, m1 = m3 = 2, m2 = 1.

It means that both: b) and d) are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case where

```
A = 3 3 3 2 2 1

m1 = 3, m2 = 2, m3 = 1, n = 6
```

If we sort using quicksort (qs) in the ways given we get:

```
qs(A[3+1..6]) ->  3 3 3 [1 2 2]

qs(A[1..2+3]) ->  [1 2 3 3 3] 2

qs(A[3+1..6]) ->  1 2 3 [2 3 3]
```

The final result: 1 2 3 2 3 3 is not sorted.

In this case, the result is not sorted because m2 was smaller than m1 so the minimum m1 values could not be carried over from part 3 to part 1 using part 2 as a (sort of) buffer. So we must have m1 <= m2.

- a) m1 > m2 may not work (as was shown).
- **b)** m1 < m2 is sufficient since m1 <= m2
- c) m1 >= m2 may not work, since m1 can be > m2 in this case and the example proved it is false.
- **d)** m1=m2=m3 satisfies m1 <= m2 so it is a sufficient condition for A to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The last run won't touch `part1`, so `part1` must contain `m1` smallest items of the array after the second run. If some of them are initially in `part1` that's OK; if they are in `part2` the second run will bring them to the right place; however those who are in `part3` must be shifted to `part2` first. If the array is initially in reverse order, then `m1>=m2>=m3` must be satisfied to bring `m3` least items from the right end of the array to the left one. Similary `m1<=m2<=m3` seems necessary to guarantee `m1` largest items from `part1` will be shifted to `part3`.

Final answer: d.

Comment: it is *not necessary* for m1=m2=m3 as implied by `m1>=m2>=m3` and `m1<=m2<=m3` since m2 can be larger than both m1 and m3 and the array will be sorted.